# Creating a Trigger that runs on two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, oracle19c

I have two tables, `COPY` and `BORROW`. Their columns are:

```
COPY (
Copy_id,
Bk_id,
Loc_id,
Opinion
)
```

and

```
BORROW (
Cus_evo,
B_Date,
R_Date,
Fee,
Copy_id,
Cus_id
)
```

I want to configure a trigger that ensures Copies that stored in a Exact location (London) (from `Loc-id` column of `COPY` table) cannot be Borrowed in December (from `B_Date` column of `BORROW` table).

I have created the following trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER BORROW_TRIGGER 
BEFORE INSERT ON BORROW FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF(TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(:NEW.B_Date, 'DD-MMM-YYYY'),'MMM'= 'DEC')
AND :NEW.Loc_id='LC0001')
THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20669,'CANNOT BORROW BOOKS FROM LONDON STORE DURING MONTH DECEMBER');
END IF;
END;
/
```

The trigger is not created and have errors please cloud give me correct trigger for this??

Error i have experiencing

```
Errors: TRIGGER BORROW_TRIGGER
Line/Col: 3/5 PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.LOC_ID'
```

Comment: I'm using sql-server for this

Comment: I'm using oracle sql-server for this

Comment: If you're using Oracle you aren't using SQL Server. They are completely different, and competing, products.

Comment: This is also the 3rd or 4th question I've seen today where people are trying to use what looks like Oracle Syntax for triggers in SQL Server; I'm beginning to doubt this is a coincidence.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!

There are several things you can do to improve your post and raise the chances that you'll get an answer:
1. identify the server manufacturer and version (e.g. "Oracle 19c", or "Microsoft SQLServer 15.0. 2000.5).
2. supply the actual error message(s) you're seeing.

Comment: I'm using "Oracle 19c"

Comment: Saying you are using "Oracle SQL Server" is like saying you have a Sony XBox or a Samsung iPhone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only need to perform the check when `b_date` is in December, it's more efficient to add this as a `when` condition at the top of the trigger. This also simplifies the trigger logic.

```
create or replace trigger borrow_check_trg
    before insert on borrow 
    for each row
    when (to_char(new.b_date,'MM') = '12')
declare
    l_loc_id copy.loc_id%type;
begin
    select c.loc_id into l_loc_id
    from   copy c
    where  c.copy_id = :new.copy_id;

    if l_loc_id = 'LC0001' then
       raise_application_error(-20669, 'Books cannot be borrowed from the London store during December'); 
    end if;
end;
```

Comment: This trigger is success full.

Answer (score 0):

You need to query the COPY table to get the field you need:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER BORROW_BI
  BEFORE INSERT ON BORROW
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  strLoc_id  COPY.LOC_ID%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT LOC_ID
    INTO strLoc_id
    FROM DUAL
    LEFT OUTER JOIN COPY c
      ON c.COPY_ID = :NEW.COPY_ID;

  IF TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(:NEW.B_Date, 'DD-MMM-YYYY'), 'MMM') = 'DEC' AND 
     strLoc_id = 'LC0001'
  THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20669,'CANNOT BORROW BOOKS FROM LONDON STORE DURING MONTH DECEMBER');
  END IF;
END BORROW_BI;
```

Comment: ```Errors: TRIGGER BORROW_BI
Line/Col: 12/3 PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "THEN" when expecting one of the following:

   ) , * & - + / at mod remainder rem <an exponent (**)> and or
   || multiset
The symbol ")" was substituted for "THEN" to continue.```

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the existence by using a Select statement with `COUNT` aggregation from the other table(`copy`) through use of common column (`copy_id`) among tables such as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Trg_Borrow_Trigger_BI
  BEFORE INSERT ON borrow
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE    
    v_exists INT;  
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*)
      INTO v_exists
      FROM copy
     WHERE copy_id = :NEW.copy_id
       AND loc_id = 'LC0001'
       AND TO_CHAR( :NEW.b_Date, 'MM' ) = '12';
      
    IF v_exists > 0 THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20669,
                              'CANNOT BORROW BOOKS FROM LONDON STORE DURING MONTH DECEMBER');
    END IF;
END;
/
```

where

- `TO_DATE()` conversion is superfluous
- to prepend `loc_id` with `:NEW` is not possible, since the trigger is created for
  the table `borrow` has not this column, while `copy` table has.

Comment: This is Trigger Successfully created but in there Location is omitted.